# iptables NAT not applied to packets from a TAP interface

Tags: networking, iptables, netfilter, tun-tap

The iptables MASQUERADE NAT rule is not being applied to packets that have come from a TAP interface.

I have an application tied to two TAP interfaces that is used for some packet manipulation during routing.

I am using *iptables* to apply a netfilter mark to packets received on one of two physical interfaces and *ip rules* to route the packets into one of my TAP interfaces.  When the packet comes out my application it goes back into the main routing table and out the appropriate physical interface.

I have a MASQUERADE NAT rule on one of the two physical interfaces, but when the packet is transmitted the NAT is not applied.  I **think** this is because it has already passed through iptables already.

Can you mark a packet as "new" in iptables so it traverses the full iptables chains a second time?

Comment: I should note that I can apply a different netfilter mark to packets being transmitted from my TAP interfaces, so the output packets are traversing the iptables chain.

Comment: Can you post your current rules?

Comment: I've actually worked out the answer - was quite an interesting one.  Because the "same packet" had already been through the netfilter work flow once before the sessions had already been through conntrack and was in the ESTABLISHED state.  Since packets only the NEW state go through the NAT chains the MASQUERADE was not applied.  I resolved my issue by telling netfilter to not push packets on my raw interfaces through conntrack.... iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i [interface] -j NOTRACK